# Applying spread from tidyr on ffdf

Tags: r

On a normal dataframe I could spread out all data according to a particular column. But how can I do this on an ffdf .

I have an input like this.

```
         Uid      article_Topic frqnu
1 1234567890      Cricket  2
2 1234567891      Cricket  3
3 1234567892      Cricket  4
4       abcd      Cricket  5
5 1234567894      Cricket  6
6 1234567890 Food Package  2
7 1234567895     FootBall  7
```

spread(data=ffg1,article_Topic,frqnu,fill=0) on a data.frame gives

```
      userID Cricket Food Package FootBall 
1 1234567890       2            2        0 
2 1234567891       3            0        0 
3 1234567892       4            0        0 
4 1234567894       6            0        0 
5 1234567895       0            0        7 
6 1234567896       0            0        0 
7       abcd       5            0        0
```

Any other way of achieving a similar output would also be of help. I need to do this on an ffdf
I am not much familiar with R as of now. Any help is appreciated.

**Update :** 
I tried to do this

```
library(ff)
library(ffbase)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
ffg= read.csv.ffdf(file="text.txt",header=FALSE,sep="\t")
colnames(ffg)<-c("userID","article_Topic","frqnu")
spread(data=ffg,article_Topic,frqnu,fill=0)
```

Which gives an error : no applicable method for 'spread_' applied to an object of class "ffdf"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `ffdfdply` from `library(ffbase)` to perform a split-apply-combine on a `ffdf` object.  It splits the object according to the the `split`, applies the `FUN` to the 'data', and stores the result as an `ffdf` object.  So, inside the `FUN`, we can use our regular `dcast`

```
library(ffbase)
library(reshape2)
ffdfdply(x=ffg, split=ffg$userID, FUN= function(x) {
          dcast(x, userID~article_Topic, value.var='frqnu', fill=0)
 })
```

Or `spread` syntax.

```
library(tidyr)
ffdfdply(x=ffg, split=ffg$userID, FUN= function(x) {
         spread(x, article_Topic, frqnu, fill=0)
})
```